# Remove files by using placeholder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to remove several files from a directory using python. The shell command would look like

```
rm *_some.tex
```

When I use something like this in python, nothing get's deleted:

```
intermediates = ('*_some.text', '*_other.text')
for intermediate in intermediates:
    if os.path.isfile(intermediate):
        os.remove(intermediate)
```

How can I achieve the shell behavior in python?

Comment: `os.path.isfile` doesn't automatically expand globs. You will probably want to look into the [`glob` module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/glob.html).

Comment: If you had put `print(intermediate)` in the `if` statement block, you would have discovered how many times `os.remove` is executed.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy: Yes, and I still would't have known why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you'll need to use `glob` or `fnmatch` to properly shell expand globs. Plus `if os.path.isfile: os.remove` leads to some race conditions. This is nicer:

```
import glob

globtexts = ('*_some.text', '*_other.text')
files = [glob.glob(globtext) for globtext in globtexts]
# try saying that line out loud five times fast....
for file in files:
    try:
        os.remove(file)
    except Exception as e:
        print("There was a problem removing {}: {!r}".format(file, e))
```

Answer (score 2):

Or, right next to `glob` in the Python documentation is `fnmatch`

```
import fnmatch
import os

for file in os.listdir('.'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*_some.text') or fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*_other.text'':
        os.remove(file)
```

To do this recursively from `/home`, for example, use `os.walk`

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/home'):
    for file in files:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*_some.text') or fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*_other.text'):
            os.remove((root+'/'+file))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I accepted Adam Smith's answer, because he used list comprehension, which I also need (although you didn't know).

Comment: It was my pleasure.  I was testing @Adam Smith's `glob` and reading in the documentation saw `fnmatch`.  I became curious about that as well.  A little test and I learned something new.  All told it appears to have been a good day for all of us.